# Why is this particular json snippet invalid?

Tags: json

Jsonlint.com says this is invalid:

```
{
    "items": [{“tn”: “13312128124”}]
}
```

> Error: Parse error on line 2: {   "items": [{“        tn”: “1331212812
>   -------------^ Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'

I can't see why its invalid. I consulted some tutorial sites to check the syntax, but even the tutorial example is reported as invalid, for example:

```
   {  
    "Countries": [  
    { "Name": "India",  
    "Capital": "Delhi"  
    },  
    {  
    "Name": "France",  
    "Major": "Paris"  
    },  
    ]  
    }
```

(http://www.java2blog.com/2013/11/java-json-tutorial.html)
How can code in a json tutorial be incorrect even?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the quotes: “tn” has curly quotes, they should be straight like in "tn".

Same goes for the number.